# system wide perf_event_open

Tags: linux, performance, perf

Using the perf cli, we can measure system wide counters :

```
$ sudo perf stat -e cpu-cycles
^C
 Performance counter stats for 'system wide':

     4 247 009 923      cpu-cycles                                                  

       2,183469627 seconds time elapsed
```

On the perf_event_open [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html), I assume it would be te equivalent of monitoring any pid (pid == -1) on any cpu (cpu == -1) but it doesn't seem to be possible :

```
   Arguments
   The pid and cpu arguments allow specifying which process and CPU
   to monitor:

   pid == 0 and cpu == -1
          This measures the calling process/thread on any CPU.

   pid == 0 and cpu >= 0
          This measures the calling process/thread only when running
          on the specified CPU.

   pid > 0 and cpu == -1
          This measures the specified process/thread on any CPU.

   pid > 0 and cpu >= 0
          This measures the specified process/thread only when
          running on the specified CPU.

   pid == -1 and cpu >= 0
          This measures all processes/threads on the specified CPU.
          This requires CAP_PERFMON (since Linux 5.8) or
          CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability or a
          /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid value of less than 1.

   pid == -1 and cpu == -1
          This setting is invalid and will return an error.
```

What is the workaround here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like none of those options aggregate counts for you, they either count on one core, or virtualize the counters across context switches for a single thread (or a single-threaded process).

If you look at what system-wide `perf stat -a` does (e.g. with `strace -f perf stat`), you can see it calls `perf_event_open` once per event per core.  It has to add up the counts for an event across cores; the system-call API won't do that for you.

Comment: Alternatively, one can add `-vv` to perf command line to see how it configures events (e.g. `perf stat -vv -e cycles`).